# Unity launcher shortcut to a terminal command

Tags: command-line

I've downloaded from the USC an app that grabs colors with the mouse (result shows in the terminal) and I'm trying to add a unity launcher app to run that command in the gnome-terminal.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Grab Color
Exec=gnome-terminal -x grabc
Categories=Development;
Icon=/home/diogo/.local/share/applications/colorline.png
```

The problem is that when I click the icon the terminal opens and closes. I just want it to be open in order to see the grabbed color.

Can someone help me? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple shell script to grab the color and copy the output to clipboard and using that in the desktop file

Here is the shell script.
I have named it as `grab.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
OUT=`grabc`
echo ${OUT} | xclip -sel clip
```

Change your .desktop contents

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Grab Color
Exec= sh /home/user/grab.sh
Categories=Development;
Icon=/home/diogo/.local/share/applications/colorline.png
```

This will copy the output to clipboard. You need to have xclip installed. If its not installed. Install it using command.

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

Comment: Glad that it helped you.